# Mocking in spring boot, how to mock a call that is inside the class and not from an external dependancy

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

Please see below code:

I am trying to unit test `SqlValidator`, it has a dependency `DaoFactory`, I know how to mock a response to that service but not mock a method call within that service

```
@Service
public class SqlValidator implements SelfServiceValidator {

@Autowired
private GenericDatabaseDAO.DAOFactory factory; 


public ControlStatusModel validate(ValidationStep step, String aNumber) {


GenericDatabaseDAO dao = factory.getDAO(sqlDetail);
GenericDatabaseTableModel queryData = dao.runQuery(sqlDetail.getQuery());
//other stuff}
```

I know how to mock the `factor.getDAO()` but how Do I mock the `dao.runQuery()` with the way the code is currently set up?

Here is my test so far

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SqlValidatorDisplayValueTest {

@Mock
@Autowired
GenericDatabaseDAO.DAOFactory factory; 
@InjectMocks
SqlValidator sqlValidator;

@Test
public void testKeyNotFound() {
    when(factory.getDAO(any(SqlDetail.class))).thenReturn(null);
    List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
    row.put("id", 1);
    results.add(row);
    GenericDatabaseTableModel data = new GenericDatabaseTableModel(results);
    //mock dao.runQuery() here?
}

}

GenericDatabaseTableModel queryData = dao.runQuery(sqlDetail.getQuery());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
    GenericDatabaseDAO dao = Mockito.mock(GenericDatabaseDAO.class);
    when(factory.getDAO(any(SqlDetail.class))).thenReturn(dao);
    List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
    row.put("id", 1);
    results.add(row);
    GenericDatabaseTableModel data = new GenericDatabaseTableModel(results);
    when(dao.runQuery(sqlDetail.getQuery())).thenReturn(//what you want to return);
    i believe you have to mock sqlDetail also.
```